# spring boot refresh the properties files without config server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I want to refresh the properties files in spring boot.

version - 2.1.4.RELEASE

In case of spring config server have to connect all my app to config server which i dont want as our application is in prod and we dont want a bigger change.
Is it possible in the same application i can refresh the prop file using config server if not using config server then using some spring code 
can i do it.
NOT application.properties , Have a application-optional.properties outside of project want to refresh only this.

Answer (score 0):

The `RefreshEndpoint` is provided by Spring Cloud. Adding the spring cloud starter config will get you the required beans and API to refresh.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Additionally you will need to expose the API via `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include="health,info,refresh"` or you can use `"*"` to expose every enabled actuator endpoint to the web.

Comment: Thanks for the ans.But spring-cloud-starter-config needs a git repo but i dont need it.I just have one optional properties file so i just want to refresh it.Nothing much more.

Comment: No it doesn't need a git repo, `Other sources are any JDBC compatible database, Subversion, Hashicorp Vault, Credhub and **local filesystems.**` You need all the functionality the starter provides to be able to refresh properties correctly, the actuator API is just _one_ part of it.

Comment: Sorry,but i dont want to use then spring config server because have to connect my app to spring config server.I just have a optional properties file outside my project.Just want to reload the value calling some get method.

Comment: @Nayak have u solve this issue? i also want to refresh without actuator and without spring config server.